# Vagrant won't says box doesn't exist

Tags: vagrant, fedora-23

I try to get a vagrant environment up and running. It has worked flawlessly before.

I go to my environment and do vagrant up.
Vagrant won't find the box and goes to Hashicorp to look for it, even if it is registered locally.

```
[<username>@localhost sugarcrm-vagrant-base]$ vagrant version
Installed Version: 1.8.1
Latest Version: 1.8.1

You're running an up-to-date version of Vagrant!

[<username>@localhost sugarcrm-vagrant-base]$ vagrant box list
<companyname>/opensuse132-sugarcrm75-base (virtualbox, 0)

[<username>@localhost sugarcrm-vagrant-base]$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'libvirt' provider...
==> default: Box '<companyname>/opensuse132-sugarcrm75-base' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: libvirt
    default: Box Version: >= 0
The box '<companyname>/opensuse132-sugarcrm75-base' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/<companyname>/opensuse132-sugarcrm75-base"]
Error: The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The box is made of 2 things:

- the name
- the provider (can be VirtualBox, VMWare, AWS ...)

when you run `vagrant up` even if you do not specify the provider it assumes it is libvirt, thats what vagrant tells you `Bringing machine 'default' up with 'libvirt' provider...`

you probably have set the env variable `VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER` to libvirt as by default virtualbox is the default provider

but when you look at your box list, you only get machine for virtualbox provider

run `vagrant up --provider=virtualbox` and then everything will work

Comment: The vagrant instance started, which solves the problem. What I don't understand is that my Vagrant file does contain config.vm.provider which is set to virtualbox

Comment: right but the config.vm.provider block is read after the VM is cloned to make provider specific parameter. not to identify which provider to use, you can have multiple provider block in the same Vagrantfile for different providers you could use (a local one like vb or vmware and a cloud block like AWS, DO ...)